# Issues injecting autowired dependency in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm getting a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for the @Autowired AccountRepository in the code below with the error message: `No qualifying bean of type [com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.dao.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.`. I have added the package containing the repository to @ComponentScan but for some reason it is still not seeing it. Dependency injection works everywhere else in my project, just not in this particular file.

```
package com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.configuration;

import com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.dao.AccountRepository;
import com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.domain.entity.Account;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.dao")
public class GlobalAuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  AccountRepository accountRepository;

  @Override
  public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
  }

  @Bean
  UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {

      @Override
      public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(account != null) {
          return new User(
            account.getUsername(),
            account.getPassword(),
            true, true, true, true,
            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER")
          );
        } else {
          throw new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find the user '" + username + "'");
        }
      }

    };
  }

}
```

And here is the repository:

```
package com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.dao;

import com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.domain.entity.Account;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

  public Account findByUsername(String username);

}
```

And the main application config:

```
package com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.configuration;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfiguration.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here's the full log and stack trace: http://pastebin.com/PKvd8rXV

**EDIT** [Here is the git repository](https://github.com/brahalla/PhotoAlbum-api), the code in question is in branch `develop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the solution to the problem, and I just wanted to make sure that I posted it here.

First of all, I moved all of the web configuration options to a single class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Second, I had to change the annotation for the AuthenticationManagerBuilder initialization to @Autowired instead of @Override. Third, I had to make the UserDetailsService bean public:

```
package com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.configuration;

import com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.dao.AccountRepository;
import com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.domain.entity.Account;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  AccountRepository accountRepository;

  @Autowired
  public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
      .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
      //.and().authorizeUrls()
      /*.and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
      .and().logout()
        .permitAll()*/
      .and().httpBasic()
      .and().csrf()
        .disable();
  }

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {

      @Override
      public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(account != null) {
          return new User(
            account.getUsername(),
            account.getPassword(),
            true, true, true, true,
            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER")
          );
        } else {
          throw new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find the user '" + username + "'");
        }
      }

    };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The classes with annotations like @controller,@service,@component, @Repository etc will be the candidates for auto wiring and the other classes are not.so consider annotating your class accordingly for proper auto wiring.

**@Component** --> generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component

**@Repository**--> stereotype for persistence layer

**@Service** --> stereotype for service layer

**@Controller** --> stereotype for presentation layer (spring-mvc)

The following code should work

```
 @Repository
 public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

  public Account findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't need the @Repository annotation. Extending CrudRepository takes care of that; this is just the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your `ApplicationConfiguration` class.

Comment: Is Spring loading your `GlobalAuthenticationConfiguration` ? Maybe `@Import` will help? Any logs from start would be useful.

Comment: Yes it is. The app runs and works just fine if I remove this particular class from the project, and I only get the stack trace when this file is there. Heres the full log and stack trace: http://pastebin.com/SqXu4zbS

Answer (score 0):

Can you post debug logs of the application?. It will give an idea whether the bean was created. Try to place componentscan in applicationconfiguration class and mark GlobalAuthenticationConfiguration with @component or relevant annotation

Comment: I've updated the logging level to debug and updated the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/PKvd8rXV

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below snippet :

```
package com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.dao;

import com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.domain.entity.Account;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

  public Account findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Also, annotate your `ApplicationConfiguration` with `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: See below, I have already tried this. Heres the log: http://pastebin.com/VjAgK2CK

Comment: Can you try with annotating `@Component` on `ApplicationConfiguration` class along with  `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: Why would I put @Component on the main Spring Boot configuration class? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

1) Could you try to put your class `ApplicationConfiguration` class in the root package `com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum` instead of `com.brahalla.PhotoAlbum.configuration` ?

Actually, `@SpringBootApplication` scans subpackages of where it's located.

See [Reference Guide 14.2 Locating the main application class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

2) As other said, put `@EnableJpaRepositories` at your class `GlobalAuthenticationConfiguration`

With this two configurations, it should work

Comment: I tried this, and am still getting the same stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue this issue is exactly due to the Spring Boot ApplicationConfiguration.java being created inside a specific package than in the root. I moved it to root It worked fine.

i.e initially it was in com.myproject.root.config, i moved it to com.myproject.root